# SQL Server 2014 time outs while running backups

Tags: sql-server, performance, azure, azure-web-app-service, database-performance

We have a SQL Server 2014 database running in virtual machine withing Azure.

The virtual machine has these specs: D13, 8 cores, 56Gb RAM which is one of the top options available from Azure.

While running backups, the database causes timeout errors to the web application (roughly 100 concurrent users).

I would expect a top notch hardware from Azure to manage backups and attend users requests without struggling.

Is this something acceptable? What alternatives could I implement to avoid this?

Comment: Are you using the backup feature for web apps or is this purely a SQL backup?

Comment: pure sql backup from management studio

Answer (score 1):

Try Implementing backups using Split Backup mechanism. This will use multiple threads to backup your database and the time taken to complete backup process is less.

Reference: http://www.sqlideas.com/2011/08/split-database-full-backup-to-mupltiple.html

For huge databases this is the best approach in my opinion